# Firebase ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) setting a huge value (e.g. 1570654658313)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set one of my firebase fields e.g. serverTime to Firebase server time using `ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`
But it's setting huge values e.g. 1570654658313. It used work properly, did something change on firebase side? How to fix this issue?

Comment: by the way I am calling this from android app sample code ```DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDbReference.getRoot().child(Constants.SERVER_TIME_PATH); ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);```

Comment: When you say "used to work properly", what exactly did it do before that's different than what you see now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` writes a UNIX-style timestamp, which is the number of milliseconds that have passed since the epoch. The value you gave corresponds to "Wed Oct 09 2019 13:57:38 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" after converting it to a date.

A quick way to validate that is to convert the number back to a date in JavaScript:

```js
console.log(new Date(1570654658313))
```

In Java the equivalent would be `new Date(new Timestamp(1570654658313).getTime())`.

Comment: An even quicker way to validate it is to paste the number into a tool like this: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Thanks Frank, check this site https://www.unixtimestamp.com, that value is too big.I use ```Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance(); instance.setTimeInMillis(firebaseServerTime); ```

Comment: looks like my Java code is working fine with `Calendar`  too, false alarm, there is some other issue, I may need to look into. Thanks Frank

Comment: unixtimestamp.com seems to count seconds, while Firebase Realtime Database counts milliseconds. So that'd explain a 1000x difference.